# How can i show embaded api map which is come from api Flutter.?

Tags: flutter, dictionary

This is my address which is provided from Backend.

```
"<iframe src=\"https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3022.681138843672!2d-73.89482218459395!3d40.747041279328165!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89c25f01328248b3%3A0x62300784dd275f96!2s7232%20Broadway%20%23%20308%2C%20Flushing%2C%20NY%2011372%2C%20USA!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sbd!4v1652467683397!5m2!1sen!2sbd\" width=\"600\" height=\"450\" style=\"border:0;\" allowfullscreen=\"\" loading=\"lazy\" referrerpolicy=\"no-referrer-when-downgrade\"></iframe>"
```

So how can i show this map address in side flutter application..???

Comment: you can use flutter_inappwebview to display the URL as an widget

Comment: try to embed a webview in your app